# `scipy.minimize` how to apply global bound constraint

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am looking at an optimisation problem and trying to solve using `scipy.optimize.minimize`.
I am trying to find the minimum of some function 
`$f(\vec{x})$ with $\vec{x} = {x1,\ldots, xn}$` some `$n$` component vector.

I have constraints for each components of the form `$x1_{min} \leq x1 \leq x1_{max}$`, etc...  and a global constraint `$min \leq x1 + x2 + \ldots xn \leq max$` which I have implemented in two ways: adding two inequality constraint for each component, see

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize

or using bounds, see 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.Bounds.html#scipy.optimize.Bounds

For the general constraint I have used two inequalities. I have found that the results are different between using inequalities or bounds (this could also dependent on the seed vector on which the minimization starts).

Is there a way to apply the constraint on the sum of all the components with a bound as well?

Comment: Please transform your latex-style formulas to something readable. Yes, it sucks, that there is no support for latex. But like that, it's hard to read. If you want some bound, which depends on the value of a *variable*, it's not possible to use *variable-bounds*. That's the difference between bounded and constrained optimization (and the latter is much more hard). As you omitted the code, you are probably using two different optimizers without knowing (e.g. bound-constrained -> LBFGSB; constrained: SLSQP). Despite converging to local-optima, differences might be possible. But you gave no detail

Comment: And just some random remark: the initial-point in LBFGSB will be projected onto your bounded-feasible set. That's surely different than what happens in constrained-opt (and might result in a different start).

Comment: @sascha Many thanks for the details on the optimization. Indeed two different algorithms are used depending on using bounds or constraints. Helped a lot. Will edit the math in my post later, after I look up how to post formulas here.